# Mongoose - model.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

this is a very odd one that I don't quite understand why it's not working. I have 2 functions, one to add an item to a MongoDB collection. That is working fine. I have another function which is meant to search the collection for items matching my query. For some reason, the search function is returning 'not a function' and I'm wondering if anyone can help?

When I try and call `findSimilarEvents()` I get `TypeError: event.find is not a function` back in the console

My model:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    eventTime: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    eventLoggedFrom: String,
    eventData: Object,
    eventID: String,
    ticketID: { type: String, default: "" },
    ticketStatus: { type: String, default: "" },
    eventLastUpdated: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('event', eventSchema);
```

My working function:

```js
exports.addEventToDB = async function(eventData, eventLoggedFrom, EventID) {

  const event = new EventModel({
    eventLoggedFrom: eventLoggedFrom,
    eventData, // this is a JSON object
    eventID: eventID
  });
  await event.save();
}
```

My non-working function:

```js
exports.findSimilarEvents = async function(eventData, eventLoggedFrom) {

  const event = new EventModel();
  let similarEvents = await event.find({
    eventData: eventData
  });
  for (var i = 0; i = similarEvents.length; i++) {
    console.log("found similar event");
    console.log(similarEvents[i]);
  }

}
```

I'm happy to provide any other info if anyone has any thoughts!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
exports.findSimilarEvents = async function(eventData, eventLoggedFrom) {

  
  let similarEvents = await EventModel.find({
    eventData: eventData
  });
  for (var i = 0; i = similarEvents.length; i++) {
    console.log("found similar event");
    console.log(similarEvents[i]);
  }

}
```

try this ...

Comment: Thank you, I believe that has resolved it! I didn't think it was returning a promise...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).